# how to ban network in k8s container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, iptables, ifconfig

how to ban network in k8s container?

I used k8s to exec some third-party code, and it may be unsecure.

So I use two container(A and B) in one pod, A to get code and pass to B container, B to exec it.

To protect our network, I'd like to disable B's network. But I didn't find any method work.

Methods I have tried:

1. ifconfig eth0 down, ifdown eth0
2. iptables -P INPUT DROP, iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

Is there any other methods?

UPDATE:
finally, I use iptable to disable network of a user, then switch to the user in container B to execute the code.

Notice: As the network namespace of the two container is the same, iptable rules will take effect in the two container.

Answer (score 1):

Better not touch the Iptable rules which may cause network connectivity issues  in K8s. Try [Network Policy](https://docs.docker.com/network/none/) in K8s to isolate the pod, kind of disabling network for pods. It is like disabling the [network for container in docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/none/)

**UPDATE**

Also I understood that the pod contains 2 containers(A&B). I think, it not possible to disable networking only for container `B` in that pod.

Answer (score 0):

https://cilium.io/ Check this project, it allows you to do things like you mention. It allows you to define application-layer and network-layer policies based on the container/pod identity. The demo that is on their page does exactly what your trying to do.